# Transit without visa requirement for India National travelling to US (tourist visa) with 19hr layover at Heathrow Airport

Tags: uk, indian-citizens, transit-visas, lhr, twov

I am an Indian National, travelling with my husband and two kids to the US on tourist visa. I have a 19hr layover at Heathrow airport during which I plan to stay at a hotel near Paddington and explore the city. I have a return flight via same airlines the next day.

The UK Gov site shows that I am eligible for the TWOV exemptions, even the IATA site mentions the same thing.  I am confused whether I should opt for Transit Without Visa or its better to apply for a visa. Can anyone please share your experiences if you had the same journey and are there any issues faced during immigrations.

Comment: The main difference is that TWOV is not 100% guaranteed, even if on the face of it you are eligible. For example, if your outbound flight from LHR is delayed until after midnight on the day after you arrive, or cancelled.

Comment: Unless you know something about yourself that would make you undesirable in the UK, it's very unlikely that a transit without visa would be refused. And if they do, they are unlikely to do anything worse to you than make you stay at the airport until your flight out.

Comment: You already know you don't need the transit visa. Why would you want to go to the trouble of getting a visa anyway?